# Есть ли возможность в списке похожих вопросов пометить отвеченные?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, дизайн, похожие-вопросы

Просматривая вопрос мы видим список "Похожие" справа.

Есть ли возможность в этом списке как-то выделить те, у которых есть "принятый" ответ?

Думаю, что тогда список станет более функциональным.

Например, вот вопрос: [Проблема с разметкой при выводе данных PHP MYSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457593/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-php-mysql)
В списке похожих вопросов только 2 или 3 с принятыми ответами. Так если я ищу ответ, то буду первым делом просматривать похожие те, что были отвечены.

Comment: В принципе это возможно и на некоторых сайтах так и сделано: например, [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/299552), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/728197). Но не на Stack Overflow... Это только вопрос дизайна (CSS/LESS).

Comment: @MiceElf у нас вроде дизайн (пока) не зафиксирован, можно менять в разумных пределах.

Comment: Поправили. Как оказалось, должно было работать одинаково на всех сайтах. Исправление будет доступно после развертывания очередной версии движка.

Answer (score 9):

Отличная фича. Хочу такую!

Вот как это выглядит на Programmers:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё хотелось бы, чтобы вместе с названием вопроса показывался постфикс статуса, вроде [копия] или [требует правки]. Это поможет

- Находить похожие вопросы, в которых действительно есть решение
- Отмечать дубли

Comment: ну так а кто это может сделать? Я не понимаю, как ru.so организован на уровне редактора сайта. кому писать, куда стучаться, чтобы это сделать?

Comment: @cyadvert на Мету писать. Вы всё правильно сделали.

Comment: @cyadvert подробнее: возможность поменять что-то в CSS сайта есть только у разработчиков, им задачу может передать Nicolas Chabanovsky. Но сначала нужно чтобы предложение было опубликовано на Мете и получило поддержку сообщества.

Comment: спасибо. Ну тогда логичный встречный вопрос (от новичка): а поддержка сообщества в чем измеряется?

Comment: @cyadvert в голосах за вопрос или ответ. Судя по +5 на вопросе, в целом предложение хорошее.

Comment: @cyadvert четкого критерия нет, сколько голосов нужно набрать. Если вариантов много, обычно выбирается наиболее популярный.

Answer (score 5):

Вопросы без принятых ответов `answer-votes default`.
Вопросы с принятыми ответами `answer-votes answered-accepted default`.

Так что берём

```
.show-votes .sidebar-linked .answered-accepted,
.show-votes .sidebar-related .answered-accepted {
```

и добавляем нужное оформление.

Полагаю, эта штука должна быть частью темы.